# Misconception in opamp feedback

Tags: oscillator, operational-amplifier, negative-feedback, positive-feedback

Is it a misconception that feedback into inverting terminal of opamp is negative feedback and feedback into noninverting terminal will be positive feedback? I feel it is. Because all oscillators have feedback into inverting terminal and still it is called regenerative feedback.

Comment: Yes, negative feedback means a negative sign in the quantity brought to the input from the output. If you bring the output to the positive input, but somewhere between you change the sign, it's negative feedback. The reverse is also true.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen you could make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is a misconception. Negative feedback means a negative sign in the quantity brought to the input, from the output. If you bring the output to the positive input, but somewhere between you change the sign, it's negative feedback. The reverse is also true.

Here are a few simplified, graphical views:

[image: fb]

The left side of the continuous line is the negative feedback, starting ith the upper, classical representation, output to the negative input. The one below has the feedback going in the positive input, but it's inverted along the way, thus it's a negative feedback. The output will be inverted compared to the input.

The right side has positive feedback, with the upper one being the direct representation, and the one below with feedback going in the negative input, but inverted along the way, thus positive feedback.